# Executing a local application with parameters via a browser

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, browser, native

In my software, I have relied on NPAPI to directly launch a native application via the browser with parameters passed to it. Recently, all browsers are aggressively dropping support for NPAPI and the lack of that feature means a dead end for the software.

I looked into the alternatives for doing the same thing, and I got the following results.

1. Native Messaging
   By far the most suggested method, and easy to implement too. This method requires the client side system to register with the machine by changing registry values in the system (horrible user experience). I can't use this method to do the required task as this would mean a bad user experience. Moreover, the code in the extension is exploitable as it would have a session variable in it.
2. Custom URL
   Again a method that is good to use, but registering protocol is another bad user experience. Moreover, I'm not sure of the variable passing using this method.

Is there any way to achieve this that doesn't have security issues, is a good User Experience and uses a one time permission grant of access to local resources?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since no correct answer came up here and I solved the issue on my software, I thought I'll write an answer here as a future reference for someone stuck on the same process.

Accessing native applications is frowned upon heavily by browsers. You may have a good intention for the task you want to do, but that one access can be misused in multiple number of ways to harm the client computer.

I found a temporary solution with a URI scheme but I planned to drop the entire architecture that requires me to do this action.

No matter what solution you find, chances are that the code you write will be outdated within a year as browsers are slowly dropping support for this kind of stuff.

Hence, the best option is to think of a solution in design is where you don't have to do this action. It will help you maintain your code for a much longer time.

If you still want to do it. Then the following way is probably best(Windows only and as of 21/3/2017).

1. Code an executable (use any language, for example: c++) to interpret the parameters you want and provide to the command prompt with specific commands.

For example, if you want to open notepad with a particular file, then you need to provide the following command to command prompt using your executable

```
notepad args[0]
```

args[0] will be the argument you pass through the browser. If notepad is not in the PATH variable, provide that in a full path too.

2. Register a custom URI scheme in the registry of the client to launch this executable. This will be a one time thing and you can provide a registry file for the client to run.

In the end, you can call the native application via the browser link by specifying your custom URI and a parameter. In the notepad case, if your custom URI is `qwerty://` Then a call may look like

```
qwerty:// c:/Personal/temp.txt
```

Do know that this method is not without security issues and you will have to address them. I don't have solutions for that as I went to change the design instead of going for a temporary solution.